# How to remain same in every situation according to the Gita?

Tags: bhagavad-gita, gita

In Gita it is written that remain same in pain and pleasure, success and failure. I think this statement is not valid due to the following reasons below

1. Suppose somebody insults you in public domain then how can you tolerate? If you do tolerate, people will think that you are stupid and a coward.
2. How is it possible to remain constant/neutral if you are suffering from tooth pain/stomach pain at that time, or if your life partner passed away.
3. Suppose you become an IAS/IPS officer, then obviously you will be excited. It will be impossible to remain constant/neutral.
4. Suppose you failed in the exam after doing lot of hard work, then obviously you will feel sorrow. Then it will be impossible to remain constant

How to remain same in every situation according to the Gita ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well in simple words if you follow teachings of the Gita what you need to do is to detach yourself from all such activities/actions.

Many people insulted Kabir/Guru Nanak/Buddha/Mahavir but where are those people now and where are these enlightened beings? Failure in exams or becoming an IPS/IAS is just part n parcel of this journey, just live in the present, enjoy the moment and move on. Life or time just like a river never stops for anyone. You can not get attached to these activities for ever.

There is very famous verse from Gita that says:

> कर्मण्येवाधिकारस्ते मा फलेषु कदाचन । मा कर्मफलहेतुर्भूर्मा ते
> सङ्गोऽस्त्वकर्मणि ॥ ४७ ॥ **Bg. 2.47**
>
> [Translation](https://vedabase.io/en/library/bg/2/47/?query=fruits#bb718)
>
> You have a right to perform your prescribed duty, but you are not
> entitled to the fruits of action. Never consider yourself the cause of
> the results of your activities, and never be attached to not doing
> your duty.

Quoting few other verses from Gita:

> श्रीब्राह्मण उवाच परिग्रहो हि दु:खाय यद् यत्प्रियतमं नृणाम् । अनन्तं
> सुखमाप्नोति तद् विद्वान् यस्त्वकिञ्चन: ॥ १ ॥ - **ŚB 11.9.1**
>
> [Translation](https://vedabase.io/en/library/sb/11/9/1/)
>
> The saintly brāhmaṇa said: Everyone considers certain things within
> the material world to be most dear to him, and because of **attachment**
> to such things one eventually becomes miserable. One who understands
> this gives up material possessiveness and **attachment** and thus achieves
> unlimited happiness.
>
> जायापत्यगृहक्षेत्रस्वजनद्रविणादिषु । उदासीन: समं पश्यन्
> सर्वेष्वर्थमिवात्मन: ॥ ७ ॥ **ŚB 11.10.7**
>
> [Translation](https://vedabase.io/en/library/sb/11/10/7/)
>
> One should see one’s real self-interest in life in all circumstances
> and should therefore remain **detached** from wife, children, home, land,
> relatives, friends, wealth and so on.
>
> यदा चित्तं प्रसीदेत इन्द्रियाणां च निर्वृति: । देहेऽभयं मनोऽसङ्गं तत्
> सत्त्वं विद्धि मत्पदम् ॥ १६ ॥ **ŚB 11.25.16**
>
> [Translation](https://vedabase.io/en/library/sb/11/25/16/?query=detached#bb82539)
>
> When consciousness becomes clear and the senses are **detached** from
> matter, one experiences fearlessness within the material body and
> detachment from the material mind. You should understand this
> situation to be the predominance of the mode of goodness, in which one
> has the opportunity to realize Me.